# Is it possible to do a more concise IF x = 1 OR x = 2 OR x = 3 in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-performance

The following is a part of a formula I'm using to filter for week day rows (for conditional formatting):

```
    OR(
        MOD(ROW(),7)=2,
        MOD(ROW(),7)=3,
        MOD(ROW(),7)=4,
        MOD(ROW(),7)=5,
        MOD(ROW(),7)=6
    ),
```

What I really want to be able to say is something like the below pseudo-code:

```
    OR(
        MOD(ROW(),7) IN (2,3,4,5,6)
    ),
```

**Is there a way of doing that?** I prefer the non-repating, more concise, and (I think) more performant nature of the proposed version.

Performance isn't something I expected to have to think about but this is a snippet of a pretty long formula I'm running on every cell in a spreadsheet and it gets quite slow.

Comment: What about `MOD(ROW(),7)>1`?

Comment: That is perfect. Why didn't I think of that?! Doesn't quite answer my general question, but perfectly suits my real-world use case. Thank you!

Can you write that as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the result of `MOD(ROW(),7)` can have 2 inappropriate values (0 and 1) and 5 suitable values (2..6), it makes sense to check the condition for a shorter sequence:

`MOD(ROW(),7)>1`

In this case, there is no need to connect multiple conditions using `OR()`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your general question.

```
=COUNTIF({2,3,4,5,6},MOD(ROW(),7))>0
```